# Create graph of adjacency matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have the following adjacency matrix:

[image: this is my adjacency matrix]

The rows represents `B1` to `B8`
and the column presents `W1` to `W8`.

How can I create a graphical representation of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`digraph`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) (introduced in R2015b) function to represent an adjacency matrix:

```
A = round(rand(8)); % create adjacency matrix
plot(digraph(A)); % plot directed graph
```

[image: Directed graph]

In case of a symmetric matrix, you can plot an undirected graph using [`graph`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html) (introduced in R2015b too):

```
A = rand(8);
A = round((A+A.')/2); % create a symmetric adjacency matrix
plot(graph(A)); % plot undirected graph
```

[image: Undirected graph]

**Converting your adjacency matrix to the expected format**

MATLAB expects that the rows ans columns have the same meaning in an adjacency matrix, which is not the case in your question. Therefore, we should add dummy rows (for `W1` to `W8`) and columns (for `B1` to `B8`).

```
A_ = round(rand(8)); % creates your adjacency matrix
A = [zeros(size(A_))' A_; A_' zeros(size(A_))]; % converts to the expected format

% gives the columns a points a name 
names = {'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8'};
plot(graph(A, names)); % create the undirected graph as demonstrated earlier
```

[image]

**Alternatives**

- [Using `gplot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284384/7621674) may be useful for older MATLAB versions

  ```
  gplot(A, [zeros(8, 1) (1:8)'; 5*ones(8, 1) (1:8)'])
  set(gca,'XTick',[0 5])
  set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'B', 'W'})
  ```

From R0126b, the last two lines *may* be written somewhat nicer as:

```
xticks([0 5]);
xticklabels({'B', 'W'})`
```

[image]

- [For a large amount of points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19465937/7621674)

Comment: W and B are different  for first row for example you see it B1 is connected to W1 and W4

Comment: I have added a paragraph about converting your matrix to the expected format.

Comment: sorry if very bad in matlab but i tried code 
http://imgur.com/noskzBO
and got http://imgur.com/GkTG4kb

Comment: @m7913d Nice answer! The [`graph`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html) and [`digraph`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) functions were Introduced in MATLAB R2015b. Since it's a fairly recent release, I suggest adding this somewhere in your answer.

Comment: @EbraamEmil What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: So, you can try the `gplot` approach for that version of MATLAB

Comment: You should not use `graph` with your version of MATLAB, so the error can not be the same or you forgot to remove your old code from your script.

Comment: i tried gplot method 
with
xticks([0 5])
xticklabels({'B', 'W'})
got
Undefined function 'xticks' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in projectbackup (line 189)
xticks([0 5])

Comment: In that case, your `A` is not correct, you should use the one from _Converting your adjacency matrix to the expected format_. Note that i edited my code